# C# code for open/close drawer and printing the receipt at the same time?

Tags: c#, list, crystal-reports, slidingdrawer, thermal-printer

Does any body know how to create a C# application that can open a drawer connected to the computer and print receipt at same time?

Drawer Name: PCD-354 Electronic Cash Drawer

Cash receipt printer: Epson TM-T88v

Comment: How could we possibly give you code for unspecified hardware?

Comment: Something tells me you're better of reading the API reference for your hardware/software rather than hoping some random developer will just happen to know the API by heart.

Comment: try to use this link buddy it will help.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/posfordotnet/thread/968d7d90-9376-4fee-9838-b79ec0e630e3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.PointOfService;

namespace POS
{
public class CashDrawerClass
{
  CashDrawer myCashDrawer;
  PosExplorer explorer;

 public CashDrawerClass()
{
 explorer = new PosExplorer(this);
 DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer");
 myCashDrawer = explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);
}

 public void OpenCashDrawer()
  {
  myCashDrawer.Open();
  myCashDrawer.Claim(1000);
  myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
  myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
  myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = false;
  myCashDrawer.Release();
  myCashDrawer.Close();
  }
}
}
```

try that. maybe it will help you have an overview on things

Comment: Thanks, but I also have to have a code for the printing of receipts do you have any idea?

Comment: it doesn't work for me, should I change explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer") to something?

Comment: @AllanChua; did you find solution to your problem? I am having the same problem. My cash drawer is connected to the receipt printer