# Open Cash Drawer

Tags: c#, wpf, point-of-sale, pos-for-.net

I need to open Cash Drawer in my WPF application, this is the first time I deal with Cash Drawer, after some search I have knew that I'll use Microsoft Point of Services. So I have installed POSforDotNet V1.14 and start new project and added the reference, I have found this example :

```
CashDrawer myCashDrawer;
PosExplorer explorer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    explorer = new PosExplorer();
    DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer");
    myCashDrawer = explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myCashDrawer.Open();
    myCashDrawer.Claim(1000);
    myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
    myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
    myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = false;
    myCashDrawer.Release();
    myCashDrawer.Close();
}
```

You can download my test application [HERE](http://alrakiza.ly/CashDrawerApp.rar)

I have tried but it dose not work :(

> gave me error in myCashDrawer =
>   explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo); line

Please can help me because I'm stuck with Microsoft Point of Services and I'm not fully understand it.

Comment: Can you define 'does not work'?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Thanks for your time ,It gave me error in myCashDrawer = explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo); line. you can download the test application

Comment: You need to also post the error you received in your original question.  I seem to remember when I used POS for .NET that there was a separate application that needed to be used to claim the device on the windows level.  You might try researching that.

Comment: Upvote on @alan specifically for "post the error".

Comment: Do you have a OPOS cashdraw named CashDrawer set up ? You can check in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\CashDrawer` there should be a sub key named `CashDrawer`. Also how is the cashdraw connected to the computer, direct connect or via a printer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736676/c-sharp-code-for-open-close-drawer-and-printing-the-receipt-at-the-same-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736676/c-sharp-code-for-open-close-drawer-and-printing-the-receipt-at-the-same-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736676/c-sharp-code-for-open-close-drawer-and-printing-the-receipt-at-the-same-time

you need to try this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to typecast to `CashDrawer`. I updated your code now sure you will not get error.

```
myCashDrawer = (CashDrawer)explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the (CashDrawer) cast, I'd recommend to use

```
DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer", "LOGICAL DEVICE NAME for your cash drawer");
```

If you had more than one installed and you just use one parameter, it'll throw an error (and MSPOS v1.14 installs a phony cash drawer for testing, so you've got at least your physical and that one).

Answer (score 0):

```
            System.IO.Ports.SerialPort port = null;
            port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(Program.CashDrawerPort);
            port.PortName = Program.CashDrawerPort;
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            port.RtsEnable = true;
            try
            {
                port.Open();
                if (port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.Write("B");
                }
                else
                {
                }
                port.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exceptionMessage)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)