# C# code to open regular HP QT457AA cashdrawer

Tags: c#, c++, vba

I got a HP QT457AA cashdrawer connected with a RJ-12 cable with HP RP7800 (which has a RJ-12 Slot).

I have searched for along time but couldnt find anything helpful how to open it( directly - without receipt Printer)

I downloaded PoS SDK like in this thread: [Open Cash Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364208/open-cash-drawer)
The problem is there are often examples how to something with a cashdrawer that is connected through COM port, but mine is connected with RJ-12 and thats why im struggling with it

But im rather clueless with Visual Studio 2015.
I know i'm asking alot , so I would be very thankful for help.

edit: forgot to mention that I tested if it opens automatically by using Test Apps from OPOS and Microsoft POS SDK and it worked after claiming and "opening" it

Comment: It doesnt look like that code really worked out for that person either. You might have a better change looking here:http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5166953 They have a list of technical manuals and data sheets. I have worked on things like this in the past and it can be a headache. I have even gone as far as placing a sniffing program in between the connectors to sniff out the commands that machine was sending/recieving.

Comment: Yeah the sad part is that HP doesn't provide anything useful on doing things like this. The sniffing idea was exactly what I was thinking about, sadly impossible for me.

Comment: When it comes to hardware hacking, nothing is impossible. To begin this process, all you need is a Rj-12 to serial adapter, then serial to usb or if you have a computer with a decent serial you wouldnt need the USB option. At that point, any serial sniffer will work and you can start from there. HP wants to sell you their high end POS software so I highly doubt this will be easy. But when you are done, and you cracked it and have running code for it you will look back and realize how f'n awesome it all was.

Comment: You tagged your question in VBA. If you are using Visual Studio, you probably meant VB.NET. They are two distinct and incompatible languages.

Answer (score 0):

[Download the correct HP Drivers for your computer's cash drawer port](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-rp7-retail-system-model-7800/5263782%20%22HP%20Drivers%20for%20your%20compputer)

If OPOS drivers installed, you can download HP OPOS Logical Name Utility from the link above. You can give whatever name you want to your device then you can access it by calling the name. You don't need to deal with any ports. Search for samples for OPOS Cash Drawer control or use the sample in Microsoft Point of Service SDK.

[Microsoft Point of Service for .NET v1.14 (POS for .NET)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42081)